# Query to get employees data in a given date/period

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need help for getting employees work data from a, for me, complex database.

I'll try to resume the database organization:

1. **employees** table that, at very minimum is as follows

```
id    | name
16063 | Jane
17594 | Joe
```

2. **history** table with dates of start/end working periods:

```
id   | id_employee | start    | end
1518 | 16063       | 20110701 | 20991231
1576 | 17594       | 20201123 | 20210715
1577 | 17594       | 20210716 | 20991231
```

3. **employment_type**

```
id | description
3  | permanent
4  | fixed-term
```

4. **employment_status**

```
id   | id_employee | start    | id_employment
1518 | 16063       | 20210901 | 3
1575 | 17594       | 20201123 | 4
1576 | 17594       | 20210716 | 3
```

5. **positions**

```
id | description
5  | Assistant
26 | Collaborator
56 | Manager
```

6. **position_status**

```
id   | id_employee | start    | id_position
1545 | 16063       | 20190101 | 5
1546 | 16063       | 20210901 | 26
1603 | 17594       | 20201123 | 56
```

7. **levels**

```
id | description
7  | C
9  | D
20 | ME1B
```

8. **level_status**

```
id   | id_employee | start    | id_level
1525 | 16063       | 20190101 | 7
1526 | 16063       | 20210901 | 9
1583 | 17594       | 20201123 | 20
```

I need help for a query that, f.i., in the period January 1st and December 31th of 2021 returns:

```
id    | name | employment | position     | level | start      | end
16063 | Jane | permanent  | assistant    | C     | 20110701   | 20991231
16063 | Jane | permanent  | collaborator | D     | 20110701   | 20991231
17594 | Joe  | fixed-term | manager      | ME1B  | 20201123   | 20210715
17594 | Joe  | permanent  | manager      | ME1B  | 20210716   | 20991231
```

while testing only January 1st 2021, it should return:

```
id    | name | employment | position     | level | start    | end
16063 | Jane | permanent  | assistant    | C     | 20110701 | 20991231
17594 | Joe  | fixed-term | manager      | ME1B  | 20201123 | 20210715
```

I'm using the following query:

```
SELECT employees.id,employees.name,employment_type.description,positions.description,levels.description,history.start,history.end
FROM history 
LEFT JOIN employees ON employees.id=history.id_employee 
LEFT JOIN employment_status ON employees.id=employment_status.id_employee 
LEFT JOIN employment_type ON employment_status.id_employment=employment_type.id 
LEFT JOIN position_status ON employees.id=position_status.id_employee 
LEFT JOIN positions ON position_status.id_position=positions.id 
LEFT JOIN level_status ON employees.id=level_status.id_employee 
LEFT JOIN levels ON level_status.id_level=levels.id 
WHERE (history.start <= '20210101' OR history.end <= '20211231');
```

this gives me an incorrect output:

```
16063 | Jane | permanent  | assistant    | C    | 20110701 | 20991231
16063 | Jane | permanent  | assistant    | D    | 20110701 | 20991231
16063 | Jane | permanent  | collaborator | C    | 20110701 | 20991231
16063 | Jane | permanent  | collaborator | D    | 20110701 | 20991231
17594 | Joe  | permanent  | manager      | ME1B | 20201123 | 20210715
17594 | Joe  | fixed-term | manager      | ME1B | 20201123 | 20210715
```

As you can see, for Jane it created all combinations of positions and levels while for Joe for "permanent" it reported same dates of fixed-term one.

This is the sql of the sample database (if of any help)
Thanks in advance

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "employees" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "name"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "employment_type" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "description"   TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "positions" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "description"   TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "levels" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "description"   TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "employment_status" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "id_employee"   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "start" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "id_employment" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "history" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "id_employee"   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "start" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "end"   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "level_status" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "id_employee"   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "start" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "id_level"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "position_status" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "id_employee"   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "start" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "id_position"   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
INSERT INTO "employees" VALUES (16063,'Jane');
INSERT INTO "employees" VALUES (17594,'Joe');
INSERT INTO "employment_type" VALUES (3,'permanent');
INSERT INTO "employment_type" VALUES (4,'fixed-term');
INSERT INTO "positions" VALUES (5,'Assistant');
INSERT INTO "positions" VALUES (26,'Collaborator');
INSERT INTO "positions" VALUES (56,'Manager');
INSERT INTO "levels" VALUES (7,'C');
INSERT INTO "levels" VALUES (9,'D');
INSERT INTO "levels" VALUES (20,'ME1B');
INSERT INTO "employment_status" VALUES (1,16063,20210901,3);
INSERT INTO "employment_status" VALUES (2,17594,20201123,4);
INSERT INTO "employment_status" VALUES (3,17594,20210716,3);
INSERT INTO "history" VALUES (1,16063,20110701,20991231);
INSERT INTO "history" VALUES (2,17594,20201123,20210715);
INSERT INTO "history" VALUES (3,17594,20210716,20991231);
INSERT INTO "level_status" VALUES (1,16063,20190101,7);
INSERT INTO "level_status" VALUES (2,16063,20210901,9);
INSERT INTO "level_status" VALUES (3,17594,20201123,20);
INSERT INTO "position_status" VALUES (1,16063,20190101,5);
INSERT INTO "position_status" VALUES (2,16063,20210901,26);
INSERT INTO "position_status" VALUES (3,17594,20201123,56);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Do not link to an external site for your [example]. Put the code, **as text**, not images, into the question itself.

Comment: You've tagged *sql* but not a *specific* RDBMS. As the *sql tag* description suggests, please [TAG](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) your RDBMS

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the most efficient way to do it.

But with enough row_numbers you get rid of the duplications.

Also note that this will return the latest from employee_type, position & level, regardless of history.
Since only history has a criteria for the dates.

> ```
> SELECT 
>   emp.id as emp_id
> , emp.name as emp_name
> , emptype.description as type_desc
> , pos.description as pos_desc
> , lvl.description as lvl_desc
> , hist.start as hist_start
> , hist.end as hist_end
> FROM employees AS emp
> INNER JOIN (
>   select id_employee, h.start, h.end
>   , row_number() over (partition by id_employee 
>                      order by start desc) as rn
>   from history h
>   where (h.start <= '20210101' OR h.end <= '20211231')
> )  AS hist
>   ON hist.id_employee = emp.id
>  AND hist.rn = 1
> LEFT JOIN (
>   select id_employee, id_employment
>   , row_number() over (partition by id_employee 
>                      order by start desc) as rn
>   from employment_status 
> ) AS empstat
>   ON empstat.id_employee = emp.id 
>  AND empstat.rn = 1
> LEFT JOIN employment_type AS emptype
>   ON emptype.id = empstat.id_employment
> LEFT JOIN (
>   select id_employee, id_position
>   , row_number() over (partition by id_employee 
>                        order by start desc) as rn
>   from position_status
> )  AS posstat
>   ON posstat.id_employee = emp.id
>  AND posstat.rn = 1
> LEFT JOIN positions AS pos
>   ON pos.id = posstat.id_position
> LEFT JOIN (
>   select id_employee, id_level
>   , row_number() over (partition by id_employee 
>                        order by start desc) as rn
>   from level_status 
> ) AS lvlstat
>   ON lvlstat.id_employee = emp.id
>  AND lvlstat.rn = 1
> LEFT JOIN levels AS lvl
>   ON lvl.id = lvlstat.id_level;
> ```

| emp_id | emp_name | type_desc | pos_desc | lvl_desc | hist_start | hist_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16063 | Jane | permanent | Collaborator | D | 20110701 | 20991231 |
| 17594 | Joe | permanent | Manager | ME1B | 20201123 | 20210715 |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=94049b8dc4882b59907108e35099ec1d)*

Comment: Thanks for your code. Since the limitation you reports probably I need to use not sql but ad hoc c++ model/view implementation.

Comment: I see, well that's a whole different approach then. Good luck with that.